# How to remove border of ASP.NET ImageButton

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have the following C# markup:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn" runat="server" CssClass="accordion-icon-close" value="" 
     CommandName="Edit" />
```

The css class is defined as follows:

```
.accordion-icon-close
{
    background-image: url("../Images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -32px -16px;
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

It's a no-brainer really, but somehow IE manages to meddle with the borders surrounding the image (because it's really an input tag in HTML) so that they're always visible. The HTML markup is:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvByPriorityCount$ctl02$imgBtn" id="MainContent_gvByPriorityCount_imgBtn_0" class="accordion-icon-close" value="" src="" />
```

**My Question:**
How do I remove the borders that IE is placing around the input tag? Firefox shows no borders, so I'm certain this is just some crappy IE behavior.

I tried using jQuery to override the CSS somehow, but to no avail.

```
$("input[type='image']").css('border-style', 'none !important;');
```

Also, I'm using IE 8 for this test.

Thanks for the help!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><link href="Styles/Test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        if ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("input[type='image']").css('outline', 'none !important;');
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Test.aspx" id="form1">

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBAKdjqv1AgKv/aZYAq/9uh0Cr/3+9QEioIHaMuCcNMLO+7F1bdAtcLLool6O9sR4U9mtwrnrYQ==" />
</div>
    <div>
    <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gvTest" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">ID</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td valign="top">
                    <input type="image" name="gvTest$ctl02$imgBtn" id="gvTest_imgBtn_0" class="accordion-icon-close" value="" src="" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;" />
                </td><td>1</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td valign="top">
                    <input type="image" name="gvTest$ctl03$imgBtn" id="gvTest_imgBtn_1" class="accordion-icon-close" value="" src="" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;" />
                </td><td>2</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td valign="top">
                    <input type="image" name="gvTest$ctl04$imgBtn" id="gvTest_imgBtn_2" class="accordion-icon-close" value="" src="" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;" />
                </td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `$("input[type=image]").css('border', '0 !important');
`

Comment: Have you tried `BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="None"` in the markup?

Comment: What happens if you add border:none to you css class? If that doesn't work, it might be an outline you see. So try to set outline:none in the css class.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe - already tried it too, didn't work

Comment: @aaberg - tried setting outline to none, didn't work

Comment: could you copy/paste the generated html source into the question?

Comment: then this shoul work `<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn" runat="server" CssClass="accordion-icon-close" BorderWidth="0" value="" CommandName="Edit" />` and set in your CSS `.accordion-icon-close { border: 0 }`

Comment: @aaberg - per your request I added the HTML. I actually setup a new test page for it with minimal amounts of data in it. I removed the ViewState from the HTML as well. The Test.css has nothing in it but the style that the ImageButton is using.

Comment: Use the F12 debugger in Internet Explorer 9, or the Firefox or Google Chrome developer console to see what styles are being applied to your image.

Comment: I can't test it on IE 9, unfortunately (I'm stuck on IE 8).  it works just fine in Firefox (so obviously there will be no border styles there).

Comment: @Zoltan - It should work, but it doesn't. Here's the wierd thing - when I refresh the page and it renders the image buttons (as HTML input tags) **they initially look correct**. But as the page finishes rendering during the last second it plops the borders around the images!

Comment: them maybe change `.ready()` to `.load()` - `$(document).load(function () {  $("input[type='image']").css('border', '0 !important'); });`

Comment: I created a fiddle with you html you supplied. http://jsfiddle.net/6HPUv/3/ I cant reproduce the error with IE9. I have tried all the compatibility modes.

Comment: @Zoltan - I gave .load() a try but it didn't do it either. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @aaberg - Thanks for trying that on IE9 for me! I'll be upgrading to Win 7 next week, and so I'll be on IE9 then as well. I'm just going to check this one off as an IE8 quirk of some type for now and quit wasting time on it. I actually had someone else test it who is on Win 7 and IE8, and they had the same thing happen.

Comment: That's something unheard of! Do you have it live somewhere to take a look at?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. It's an intranet site and authenticates from LDAP. Anyway, I'll see if I can't throw up a test site somewhere when I get a few spare minutes.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is just adding extra style within the button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="but_qt_status" style="border-width:0px"...
```

We use here IE 8 & 9